# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable; Agglomerative Clustering

Tags: python, string, types

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

iris = load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data=iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)
X = df[['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']]

linkage_method = 'ward'
distance_metric = 'euclidean'

agglomerative = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=3, linkage=linkage_method, affinity=distance_metric)
agglomerative.fit(X)

linkage_matrix = linkage_method(X, linkage_method)
dendrogram(linkage_matrix)
plt.show()
```

I've tried to research other issues and problems, but was unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is at line `linkage_matrix = linkage_method(X, linkage_method)`. You previously defined it as a string, but here you tried to call it as a function. I believe what you're looking for is the method `linkage` from `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`.

There are other problems later in your code. You tried to use `dendrogram` before defining it; this method is also available in `scipy.cluster.hierarchy`. And you forgot to import matplotlib.

At the beginning, add:

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import dendrogram, linkage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Change the code near the end to:

```
linkage_matrix = linkage(X, linkage_method)
dendrogram(linkage_matrix)
plt.show()
```